# I want to get 2 columns of text using Rmarkdown to create a report in Word

Tags: markdown, pandoc, r-markdown

Could you please show me an example how to create a 2-column text using Rmarkdown and Pandoc, and how to generate a report in Word.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `<div>` HTML tags

The **markdown** file `test.md`

```
<div style="column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate 
  ultricies eros non dignissim. Nulla metus purus, fermentum ut luctus 
  quis, elementum non felis. Mauris venenatis cursus arcu nec porta. 
  Sed sagittis euismod erat ac tincidunt. Aliquam tempus odio lectus, 
  in tempus magna fringilla sed. Praesent vel mollis odio, at tempor 
  arcu. Pellentesque iaculis felis id magna ornare mollis. Etiam mollis 
  rhoncus fermentum. Aenean faucibus feugiat risus, ac euismod dui commodo et.

  Sed in commodo arcu, vel sodales nibh. Nulla facilisi. Duis non nisl et 
  purus consectetur bibendum. Proin sed nisi pretium, eleifend risus nec, 
  interdum nunc. Morbi sed ipsum pharetra, pretium erat vitae, lacinia erat. 
</div>
```

The call to pandoc

```
 pandoc --from markdown --to html --standalone test.md -o test.html
```

The result

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate  
ultricies eros non dignissim. Nulla metus purus, fermentum ut luctus quis, 
elementum non felis. 
Mauris venenatis cursus arcu nec porta. Sed sagittis euismod erat ac tincidunt. 
Aliquam tempus odio lectus, in tempus magna fringilla sed. ...

</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The open the HTML file in MSWord